# Как help выбирает и выводит строки docstring касательно дескрипторов?

Tags: python

Совсем не могу понять и найти, как работает встроенная функция `help` в python.

Ниже приведены 3 примера (в каждом код+вывод); удивительно то, что каждый раз мы видим разный вывод функции `help`, применённой к экземпляру пользовательского класса.

Код.1

```
class Descriptor:
    'I WANT THIS DOC'

    def __init__ (self):
        self.__doc__ = 'but i got this'

    def __get__(self, inst, ownner):
        return 777

class A: data = Descriptor()

x = A()
help(x)
```

Вывод.1 (многое не показано для экономии места)

```
data = 777
```

Код.2

```
class Descriptor:
    'I WANT THIS DOC'

    def __init__ (self):
        self.__doc__ = 'but i got this'

    def __get__(self, inst, ownner):
        return inst._data            # <-- CHANGES HERE

class A: data = Descriptor()

x = A()
help(x)
```

Вывод.2

```
data
    but i got this
```

Код.3

```
class Descriptor:
    'I WANT THIS DOC'

    def __init__ (self):
        self.__doc__ = Descriptor.__doc__        # <-- CHANGES HERE

    def __get__(self, inst, ownner):
        return inst._data

class A: data = Descriptor()

x = A()
help(x)
```

Вывод.3

```
data
```

Думаю ситуация видна. Опишем подробнее, что наблюдаем в примере номер:

1. `__get__` возвращает конкретное значение. Кажется, что `help` как то понимает это, а потому решаем сразу показать нам: `data = 777`, игнорируя документацию (строки docstring)!!!
2. Когда `__get__` возвращает нам нечто, функция `help` наконец решила показать нам документацию, но правда явно прикреплённую к экземпляру дескриптора в конструкторе ('but i got this').
3. Последний пример самый "разрывной". Мы меняем только то, что в конструкторе дескриптора присваиваем строке документации экземпляра другую строку, явно извлечённую как атрибут `Descriptor`, которая (строка) нормально существует к этому моменту.

Вывод, который ожидался:

1:

```
data
    but i got this
```

2:

```
data
    but i got this
```

3:

```
data
    I WANT THIS DOC
```

4 (если бы конструктора вообще не было):

```
data
    I WANT THIS DOC
```

**Вопрос(ы):**

Что происходит?

Почему `help` ведёт себя именно так в таких различных и одновременно похожих ситуациях?!

Как, вообще не передавая экземпляру дескриптора строку в конструкторе, заставить `help` выводить строку 'I WANT THIS DOC'? Она вообще-то — наследуемый объектом `Descriptor()` атрибут и если `help` достаёт документацию как `a.__doc__` то такой атрибут есть и инициализирован! (наследование сломалось?)

Comment: `a.__class__.__doc__`? В `ipython` `magic`-оператор `?` возвращает два поля `Docstring` и `Class docstring`

Comment: если бы он доставал `a.__class__.__doc__` то должно быть и брал бы строку 'I WANT THIS DOC', но её совсем никак не получается заставить появиться.